# Problems setting up mock services and calling it with jasmine/ karma and Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a method which calls another method. Within that method I subscribe to a service, if there is a match it then uses Angular router service to navigate. Here is a [stackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-queryparam-1fztjc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch%2Fsearch.component.spec.ts)

```
  goToMain(): void {
    this.viewFunc(this.queryString);
  }

  viewFunc(queryString): void {
    this.reportService.getAnotherReport(queryString).subscribe(x => {
      if (x.label.toLowerCase() === "accept & view") {
        const url = "main";
        this.router.navigate([url], {
          queryParams: { queryString: queryString }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I successfully created a test in my spec file to test that the `viewFunc` method is called. I have then tried to mock the subscription from the service being called in the next method. Ive tried to test for two things A. the subscription is called B. if a match then navigates.

I'm getting the error "**Expected spy getAnotherReport to have been called.**"

```
  it("should call service", () => {
    const queryString = "10987";
    const testee = component;
    expect(testee).toBeTruthy();

    const routerSpy = { navigate: jasmine.createSpy("navigate") };
    const mySpy = jasmine.createSpy("getAnotherReport").and.callThrough();

    testee.viewFunc(queryString);

    expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["/main"], {
      queryParams: { queryString: queryString }
    });
  });
```

Here is a [stackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-queryparam-1fztjc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch%2Fsearch.component.spec.ts)

I cant quite get an understanding of jasmine yet and unit testing, I suspect I have incorrectly setup the describe / testbed for my spec file. Therefore if somebody can help and take a look at the [stackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-queryparam-1fztjc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch%2Fsearch.component.spec.ts) I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-queryparam-kb9qsc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch%2Fsearch.component.spec.ts)

---

There were a few typos:

First, I think you meant to declare `getAnotherReport` as a value, not as a type:

```js
let getAnotherReport = {
  text: null,
  ref: "7478B45D4D4F1400223BD2F1",
  num: 19,
  urn: "123",
  title: "Test report",
  label: "accept & view"
};
```

then, in `SearchComponent.viewFunc` you have `url = 'main'` and in your spec you have:

```js
expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["/main"], {
  queryParams: { queryString: queryString }
});
```

and it should be without `/`:

```js
expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["main"], {
  queryParams: { queryString: queryString }
});
```

And now, let's see the interesting things.

We'll first explore the first assertion:

```js
const mySpy = jasmine.createSpy("getAnotherReport").and.callThrough();
/* ... */
testee.viewFunc(queryString);
/* .... */
expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

the issue here is related to how you decided to spy `viewFunc`. In this case, you've used `spyOn(component, "viewFunc");`:
These are the relevant bits that happen under the hood when you call `spyOn`:

```js
var originalMethod = obj[methodName],
spiedMethod = createSpy(methodName, originalMethod),
```

where `createSpy` will be an *empty* spy, i.e it will simply be used to track how many times the function was called, with which arguments etc. **But it will not use the original implementation**, which is not what you want, because you also have assertions that concern `ReportService`, which resides in `viewFunc`'s original implementation.

In order to use the the initial implementation, you can use `.and.callThrough()`:

```js
// a quick look at the fact that it uses the original function
SpyStrategy.prototype.callThrough = function() {
  this.plan = this.originalFn;
  return this.getSpy();
};

reportService = TestBed.get(ReportService);
// and here we are using it
spyOn(component, "viewFunc").and.callThrough();
```

put it all together:

```js
// you can get ahold of the current spy like this
const mySpy = mockReportService.getAnotherReport.and.returnValue(
  of(getAnotherReport)
);

expect(testee).toBeTruthy();
testee.viewFunc(queryString);

expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

And now onto the second assertion:

```js
// inside providers array
{ provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy },


/* ... */

const routerSpy = { navigate: jasmine.createSpy("navigate") };

expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["main"], {
  queryParams: { queryString: queryString }
});
```

In this case, notice you're using a **different** object than what you've mocked the `Router` class with.

You'll have to use the same object that you used to mock that class in question, so a way to solve this would be:

```js
let routerSpy = { navigate: jasmine.createSpy("navigate") };

/* ... */

// inside providers array
{ provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy },

/* ... */

const mySpy = mockReportService.getAnotherReport.and.returnValue(
      of(getAnotherReport)
    );

expect(testee).toBeTruthy();
testee.viewFunc(queryString);

expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["main"], {
  queryParams: { queryString: queryString }
});
```

---

### Quick tip

I'm not very familiar with Jasmine either, but it helped me a lot to see what it does under the hood. Without having to understand every tiny detail, you can at least get an intuition to how you could solve your problem. So, when in a StackBlitz app, like the one you linked, you can:

1. open the dev tools
2. press `CTRL + P` and type `jasmine.js`(there may be more than one file, the right one is the one in which resides known methods like `callThrough` - you can check this by pressing `CTRL + SHIFT + O` and typing the method name)

additionally, you can search for `search.component.ts` and place some breakpoints there for a smoother debugging experience.

Comment: What a fantastic answer! Best answer I've seen on here for years. Thanks and hope others can use this.

Comment: Thanks! It's been a pleasure to help!

Comment: Any reason i am getting TypeError: this.mockReportService.getAnotherReport.subscribe is not a function in my local environment? As far as I can see the setup is the same as the stackblitz. line 80

Comment: @TomRudge perhaps because `mockReportService.getAnotherReport` is of 'spy' type. Try console logging it as well. Also check that you have the necessary `@types/**` installed.